# Linux for Mac dual-boot

Tags: linux, dual-boot, kde, macintosh

Does anyone know what is the minimum USB key size needed to create a bootable standard Linux OS (i.e. KDE Neon)

Also, are there any Linux distributions that work exceptionally well, or that  don't work well (including ease of installation for a dual boot) on a 2020 iMac, including OS that can fully utilize the retina display.

Comment: How easy an OS is to install on any given hardware is _extremely_ subjective and depends on you experience with the OS, with the particular hardware, and your general level of knowledge.

Comment: In the past I've installled on old Windows machines. I found more popular distro's like ubuntu seem to be more user friendly and work with different hardware better than other OS's

Comment: You need the newest version, with new kernel & drivers. Newer kernel now in new distributions: With An Out-Of-Tree Kernel Patch You Can Finally Read/Write To The SSDs On Newer Macs - 2019 July
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MacBook-Finally-Linux-SSD-RW https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview rEFInd on newer MAC with Secure Boot
https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/discussion/general/thread/1a96f5bd6d/?limit=25 Linux on M1
https://corellium.com/blog/linux-m1

Comment: Thanks so much for that Old Fred - really helpful links. I also found the standard USB capacity seems to be about 4GB (to be on the safe side) N.B. ISS flying over in about 5 minutes from now!

Comment: I was able to get Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my 2011 MBP. For the newer Macbooks, I'm not at all sure that it's possible to install a working & reliable version of Linux. Apple seems dead-set against supporting open source. That's hugely disappointing - but we do still have the option of expressing our opinion on that policy by voting with our $$